# How to keep track of which rows are filled with .fillna(value=median) in Pandas pd.merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am merging two Dataframe's together using a left merge and merging on a key that is shared between the two data frames. Since the left frame has all of the necessary rows, but the right array is missing some values in the rows, I am doing a fillna and inputing the median of a column.

What I want to be able to do track which rows are being filled with the median. I know of the ability to use Indicator=True to track whether it is left_merge, right_merge or both, but since I am forcing a left_merge, every column of indicator will be left_merge.

Here is my code for my merge:

```
median = right_frame['x'].median()
df = pd.merge(left_frame, right_frame, on='CommonKey', how='left').fillna(value=median)
```

The left frame has columns [a,b,c,CommonKey], the right frame has columns [CommonKey,x]. The left frame has more unique CommonKey's than the right frame, thus I am filling the resulting NaN x's with the median. I really need to keep track of how many x's are resulting from .fillna. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, the indicator will be either `'both'` or `'left_only'`. Assuming you don't originally have any `NaN` in the left DataFrame then `'left_only'` will indicate which values were filled with median (as those only in the left DataFrame would have `NaN` since nothing merged).

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as you describe.  Create an additional indicator column before `fillna()`

```
df = pd.merge(
    pd.DataFrame({"CommonKey":list(range(10)), **{c:np.random.randint(1,10,10) for c in list("abc")}}),
    pd.DataFrame({"CommonKey":list(range(8)), **{c:np.random.randint(1,10,8) for c in list("x")}}),
    on="CommonKey",
    how="left"
)

df.assign(fill_x=df["x"].isna()).fillna(value=df["x"].median())
```

#### output

|  | CommonKey | a | b | c | x | fill_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 8 | 4 | False |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 8 | 3 | False |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 9 | 4 | False |
| 3 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 9 | False |
| 4 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 5 | 9 | False |
| 5 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 1 | False |
| 6 | 6 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 5 | False |
| 7 | 7 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 7 | False |
| 8 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 4.5 | True |
| 9 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 3 | 4.5 | True |